# Sending Email in Symfony 3 in dev mode

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

In need help learning how to send email in development mode using the Symfony framework with the Swift_mailer library.

Here is my config_dev.yml file:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
```

And my config.yml file:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
```

And my parameters.yml file:

```
....
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: 'my_gamil_here'
mailer_password: 'my_password_here'
```

Then in my controller I have the following:

```php
public function indexAction(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('westtexascentral555@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('kaleyaw@yahoo.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'Emails/registration.html.twig',
                array('name' => 'James')
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);

    return new Response('Email sent');
}
```

Can Someone tell me what I'm going wrong.  Nothing gets sent to the email account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure, that `mailer_user` is set only to your gmail username (without host part). Let's say if I have email `myemail@gmail.com`, my username would be `myemail`.
2. Are you using 2-step verification for your gmail account? If so, additionally you need to generate app password for your account, as specified in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html#redefining-the-default-configuration-parameters):

> If your Gmail account uses 2-Step-Verification, you must [generate an App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) and use it as the value of the `mailer_password` parameter. You must also ensure that you [allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

Shortly, you can follow [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), login, select app (in this case `Mail`) and the device you want to use mailer with, press `Generate` and you will see modal with your app password, similar to this `snub udpz xcvt jrdp`. Copy this password, and use it as your gmail password (without spaces).

If this doesn't help, also check logs, usually if there is a problem with smtp server, swiftmailer prints error to the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you specified mailer host as localhost. Check this symfony docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html. And pay attention to this part:

> The gmail transport is simply a shortcut that uses the smtp transport
>   and sets these options:

```
encryption  ssl

auth_mode   login

host    smtp.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

'mailer_transport' is the protocole to send mails.
 Try to use 'smtp' instead 'gmail' :)